# What does this mean "on s'en roule une"

Tags: sens

Roule means to roll. Does this mean to steal as to roll is informal for steal?

Please explain how to translate this.

Comment: You should give more context. It could mean different things !

Answer (score 1):

*On s'en roule une* could mean different things according to the context but I can't see how it could mean "steal". Said like that in the present tense it sounds like a suggestion of something we want to do (we'd expect a question mark: *On s'en roule une ?*)

First thing that comes to my mind is [*rouler une cigarette*](https://www.wikihow.com/Roll-a-Cigarette), if one rolls their own cigarettes.

Then it could mean [*rouler une pelle*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rouler_une_pelle), although I doubt one would ask/suggest to do it if in the situation of wanting to do so (although of course in this day and age...).

In "*on s'en roule une*" *rouler* would not refer to *rouler* meaning "to swindle" (I expect that's what you mean when you say "steal").